# How do I make the Skeleton boilerplate template 'unresponsive'

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, fluid-layout, skeleton-css-boilerplate

Hi guys so I'm carrying out a project of the different types of mobile websites that are available which includes both responsive and a standard desktop website being displayed on a mobile device. Now that I've made my responsive Skeleton based website I need to make an 'unresponsive' HTML website.

Rather than go through the process of making a HTML layout, is there any chunk of code I can remove from the Skeleton framework which removes the responsive functionality of it? And makes it no longer responsive? Therefore would display a normal desktop version on a mobile browser?

Sorry if this seems like a silly question but thought I'd ask anyway.
Thanks

Comment: remove all the media queries?

Answer (score 1):

This is the responsive grid css for skeleton's `skeleton.css`:

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box; }
.column,
.columns {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box; }

/* For devices larger than 400px */
@media (min-width: 400px) {
  .container {
    width: 85%;
    padding: 0; }
}

/* For devices larger than 550px */
@media (min-width: 550px) {
  .container {
    width: 80%; }
  .column,
  .columns {
    margin-left: 4%; }
  .column:first-child,
  .columns:first-child {
    margin-left: 0; }

  .one.column,
  .one.columns                    { width: 4.66666666667%; }
  .two.columns                    { width: 13.3333333333%; }
  .three.columns                  { width: 22%;            }
  .four.columns                   { width: 30.6666666667%; }
  .five.columns                   { width: 39.3333333333%; }
  .six.columns                    { width: 48%;            }
  .seven.columns                  { width: 56.6666666667%; }
  .eight.columns                  { width: 65.3333333333%; }
  .nine.columns                   { width: 74.0%;          }
  .ten.columns                    { width: 82.6666666667%; }
  .eleven.columns                 { width: 91.3333333333%; }
  .twelve.columns                 { width: 100%; margin-left: 0; }

  .one-third.column               { width: 30.6666666667%; }
  .two-thirds.column              { width: 65.3333333333%; }

  .one-half.column                { width: 48%; }

  /* Offsets */
  .offset-by-one.column,
  .offset-by-one.columns          { margin-left: 8.66666666667%; }
  .offset-by-two.column,
  .offset-by-two.columns          { margin-left: 17.3333333333%; }
  .offset-by-three.column,
  .offset-by-three.columns        { margin-left: 26%;            }
  .offset-by-four.column,
  .offset-by-four.columns         { margin-left: 34.6666666667%; }
  .offset-by-five.column,
  .offset-by-five.columns         { margin-left: 43.3333333333%; }
  .offset-by-six.column,
  .offset-by-six.columns          { margin-left: 52%;            }
  .offset-by-seven.column,
  .offset-by-seven.columns        { margin-left: 60.6666666667%; }
  .offset-by-eight.column,
  .offset-by-eight.columns        { margin-left: 69.3333333333%; }
  .offset-by-nine.column,
  .offset-by-nine.columns         { margin-left: 78.0%;          }
  .offset-by-ten.column,
  .offset-by-ten.columns          { margin-left: 86.6666666667%; }
  .offset-by-eleven.column,
  .offset-by-eleven.columns       { margin-left: 95.3333333333%; }

  .offset-by-one-third.column,
  .offset-by-one-third.columns    { margin-left: 34.6666666667%; }
  .offset-by-two-thirds.column,
  .offset-by-two-thirds.columns   { margin-left: 69.3333333333%; }

  .offset-by-one-half.column,
  .offset-by-one-half.columns     { margin-left: 52%; }

}
```

If you want to make it non responsive, change it to this:

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.column,
    .columns {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-left: 4%;
}

.column:first-child,
      .columns:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.one.column,
      .one.columns {
  width: 4.66666666667%;
}

.two.columns {
  width: 13.3333333333%;
}

.three.columns {
  width: 22%;
}

.four.columns {
  width: 30.6666666667%;
}

.five.columns {
  width: 39.3333333333%;
}

.six.columns {
  width: 48%;
}

.seven.columns {
  width: 56.6666666667%;
}

.eight.columns {
  width: 65.3333333333%;
}

.nine.columns {
  width: 74.0%;
}

.ten.columns {
  width: 82.6666666667%;
}

.eleven.columns {
  width: 91.3333333333%;
}

.twelve.columns {
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 0;
}

.one-third.column {
  width: 30.6666666667%;
}

.two-thirds.column {
  width: 65.3333333333%;
}

.one-half.column {
  width: 48%;
}

      /* Offsets */
.offset-by-one.column,
      .offset-by-one.columns {
  margin-left: 8.66666666667%;
}

.offset-by-two.column,
      .offset-by-two.columns {
  margin-left: 17.3333333333%;
}

.offset-by-three.column,
      .offset-by-three.columns {
  margin-left: 26%;
}

.offset-by-four.column,
      .offset-by-four.columns {
  margin-left: 34.6666666667%;
}

.offset-by-five.column,
      .offset-by-five.columns {
  margin-left: 43.3333333333%;
}

.offset-by-six.column,
      .offset-by-six.columns {
  margin-left: 52%;
}

.offset-by-seven.column,
      .offset-by-seven.columns {
  margin-left: 60.6666666667%;
}

.offset-by-eight.column,
      .offset-by-eight.columns {
  margin-left: 69.3333333333%;
}

.offset-by-nine.column,
      .offset-by-nine.columns {
  margin-left: 78.0%;
}

.offset-by-ten.column,
      .offset-by-ten.columns {
  margin-left: 86.6666666667%;
}

.offset-by-eleven.column,
      .offset-by-eleven.columns {
  margin-left: 95.3333333333%;
}

.offset-by-one-third.column,
      .offset-by-one-third.columns {
  margin-left: 34.6666666667%;
}

.offset-by-two-thirds.column,
      .offset-by-two-thirds.columns {
  margin-left: 69.3333333333%;
}

.offset-by-one-half.column,
      .offset-by-one-half.columns {
  margin-left: 52%;
}
```